# d3.js: Zoom Listener - mousedown.zoom - when I drag the graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, data-visualization

I have to do a d3 graph to show some values over time. I have 15 layers with values.

In this case I have November 2011 as my first month (firstMonth = data[0];) and December 2013 as my last month (lastMonth = data[data.length-1];).

I want to put zoom on the graph to see better the information.

My problem is: what do i have to do for the values of the graph stays only between firstMonth and lastMonth when I drag it (because i don't want the graph shows the rest of the axis without values)?

I make zoom on:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 3]).x(x).on("zoom", function(){               
    d3.selectAll(".layer").remove();
    setLayers();
    focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
});
```

and in the end I call it through

```
svg.call(zoom);
```

I know that the listener when I click and drag the graph is "mousedown.zoom". So I thought in calculate the min and the max values when I click on the graph after zoom because the x domain is different. So if min > firstMonth.date && max < lastMonth.date I can dragg it.

```
svg.call(zoom).on("mousedown.zoom",function(){

    min = x.domain()[0];
    max = x.domain()[1];

    if(min > firstMonth.date && max < lastMonth.date){
        //drag the graph
    }
});
```

But now, I don't know how to do because I think there is no super (like in Java) to call the event.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEVooK

Thanks! :)